# How to get HTML Element not an Object in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to move `li` list that has attribute `data-formid` to another `ol` before I remove `li` element itself.

However, every time I move `li` that has attribute `data-formid` to another `ol`, it append `HTMLObject` not an `li` element itself, I tried my code below without working.

My HMLT Markup is like below:

```
<ol class="example">
  <li>Account</li>
  <li>Customer</li>
  <li>Computer</li>
</ol>

<ol class="example">
  <li style="position: relative;">m1
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <ol class="">
      <li data-formid="ACC:ACC01" style="position: relative;">Account
        <a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

To remove and append an element to another `ol` I defined function `removeItem(item)` as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.fa-minus-circle', function() {
    con = confirm('Are you sure delete this menu item?');
    if (con == true) {
      item = $(this).parentsUntil('li').parent()
      removeItem(item);
    }
  });

  function removeItem(item) {
    if (item.has('li')) {
      item.find('ol li').each(function(i, e) {
        var attr = $(this).attr('data-formid');
        // For some browsers, `attr` is undefined; for others,
        // `attr` is false.  Check for both.
        if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
          $('ol.example:first').append('<h1>' + e + '</h1>');
          $(this).remove();
        } else {
          console.log('element has no formid');
          $(this).remove();
        }
        item.remove();
      })
    } else {
      item.remove();
    }
  }
})
```

From JS Script above, when I clicked on remove icon, the element being click was removed, however the element to be appended to another `ol` list was not an `li` element instead it was `[object HTMLLIElement]` ([Fiddle JS](https://jsfiddle.net/ek45gj6t/))

How can I get `li` element not `Object` appended to another `ol` list?

Thanks.

Comment: It'll better to provide more html code for your `li` list .. For me I think `insterAfter()` function will be your choice [**See Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ek45gj6t/4/)

Comment: Your HTML looks like some start and end tags do not match up making malformed markup

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath, Thanks. I admitted that my `html` code is bit of mess up since it was generated from server and I copy from that. Now I have removed and cleaned up some unneccessary attributes to make it better readable. Please kindly check it again. Thanks

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, Thanks very much. It's Great working like a charm! :D

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, if you not mind, could you please explain why my code return `Object` rather than `HTML` markup? Thanks

Comment: @HouyNarun its already explained on [**each()**](https://api.jquery.com/each/) see the blue part *function
Type: Function( Integer index, Element element ).*